# Showing an SQL Value as a different Value PHP

Tags: php, sql

First of all sorry if this has already been asked, i couldn't find it.

I would like to display a number value for example '5' as 'Weapon 1'. I have tried:

```
if ($row['pld'] != 1) { echo "Weapon 1"; } else {echo "none";}
```

But it doesn't work because the number value has too be shown.
If you need more info please ask as i am a noob php coder.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `var_dump($row['pld'])` to ensure you've actually got what you think you got in that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather make an array of values to bind to a "number"(that will be index) and go like this:

```
$numbersArray = array(
    1 => 'weapon 3',
    5 => 'weapon 1',
);

$number = 5; // or $number = $row['pld']; in your case

//we check if there is an element with an index
// $number in our pre-defined array
if(isset($numbersArray[$number]))
{
   // if there is then that's what we wanna see
   $resultWeapon = $numbersArray[$number];
}
else
{
   // if there isn't then the result for echo would be 'none'
   $resultWeapon = 'none';
}

echo $resultWeapon;
```

Answer (score 0):

please explain it. what actually you want?
what i understood is you can use like below

```
echo $row['pld'] != 1 ? 'Weapon '.$row['pld'] : 'none';
```

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to throw an unexplained ternary operator at a guy who can barely program.

Answer (score 0):

Well not to complicate things, but if the number 5 is supposed to display 'Weapon 1' than why do you check for not equal to 1? I would think it should be like this:

```
if ($row['pld'] == 5) { echo "Weapon 1"; } else {echo "none";}
```

Which can also be written in this ternary fashion:

```
($row['pld'] == 5)?echo "Weapon 1":echo "none";
```

What do you mean when you say, "it doesn't work because the number value has to be shown"?